# Get artist names only from Spotify Web API's "Get a Playlist's Tracks" endpoint

Tags: spotify

## Introduction

I am using [this](https://beta.developer.spotify.com/console/get-playlist-tracks/) endpoint of the Spotify Web API. I am using the `fields` query parameter in order to solely request the data I am going to need.

## Problem

Without any filtering the JSON returned from the API will contain an array called `items`. The first key in each object of `items` is called `added_at`. In order to receive this key only the fields parameter needs to be `items(added_at)`.

There is another key in each object of `items` called `track`. Within `track` there is an array called `artists`. Each entry of `artists` has a key called `name`. So this should be the same situation as described in the second paragraph. Therefore I should get the names of the artists only by using `items(track(artists(name)))`.

Actually this does always return the whole `artists` array. It seems like the `(name)` selector is ignored.

## Example

The responses for `items(added_at, track(artists))` & `items(added_at, track(artists(name)))` are actually the same and look like this:

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "added_at": "2017-08-24T14:56:20Z",
      "track": {
        "artists": [
          {
            "external_urls": {
              "spotify": "https://open.spotify.com/artist/4V8Sr092TqfHkfAA5fXXqG"
            },
            "href": "https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/4V8Sr092TqfHkfAA5fXXqG",
            "id": "4V8Sr092TqfHkfAA5fXXqG",
            "name": "Luis Fonsi",
            "type": "artist",
            "uri": "spotify:artist:4V8Sr092TqfHkfAA5fXXqG"
          },
          {
            "external_urls": {
              "spotify": "https://open.spotify.com/artist/4VMYDCV2IEDYJArk749S6m"
            },
            "href": "https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/4VMYDCV2IEDYJArk749S6m",
            "id": "4VMYDCV2IEDYJArk749S6m",
            "name": "Daddy Yankee",
            "type": "artist",
            "uri": "spotify:artist:4VMYDCV2IEDYJArk749S6m"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

## Question

So how can I filter the artists array to only show the name of the artists by using query parameters? Am I wrong about the assumption that `items` & `added_at` can be compared to `artists` & `name` and therefore the syntax I use is wrong or is there something else that I am missing?

## Edits

- This two queries as well show the same response as the ones shown above: `items(track.artists(name))` & `items(track.artists)`.

Comment: what exactly is your question? are you failing to retrieve artists name, or do you just want to confirm an assumption?

Comment: `items(added_at, track(artists))` & `items(added_at, track(artists(name)))` deliver the same response. My assumption is that those two should deliver different responses. I actually want the names of the artists only. The query selector seems to work for `items` & `added_at` but not for `artists` & `name`. I edited my question to make my point clear.

Comment: what language do you use? what code do you have so far? it would help us more if you showed what you have tried, rather than describe how endpoint works.

Comment: Language doesn't matter due to I am trying out things in the Spotify Web API console that I linked in the first paragraph of my question. The code I have so far are the two already known queries `items(added_at, track(artists))` & `items(added_at, track(artists(name)))`. Also there is the response I get when applying both of the queries in my question.

Comment: @Bee any luck with this? I'm trying raw curl but can't get artist.name only, it returns the whole array

Comment: Unfortunately there are no updates yet. I opened an issue on their GitHub repo which you can find [here](https://github.com/spotify/web-api/issues/891). In case the bug gets fixed we probably will see it there first.

Answer (score 0):

You won't go very far by trying the endpoint via documentation webpage. Try it programatically.

Below I show how you can access the `playlists` endpoint using both direct requests (python requests) and a nice wrapper for the api (`spotipy`).

Copy your access token generated at your linked spotify's webpage into a file on the same path as this script, say, `playlists.py`.

You can get artists' name from all playlists queried like so:

```
import requests
import spotipy
import spotipy.util as util
import json

SEARCH_PLAYLIST_ENDPOINT ='https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?type=playlist'

def search_playlist(name):
    path = 'token.json'
    with open(path) as t:
        token = json.load(t)
    myparams = {'type': 'playlilst'}
    myparams['q'] = name
    resp = requests.get(SEARCH_PLAYLIST_ENDPOINT, params=myparams, headers={"Authorization": "Bearer {}".format(token)})
    pprint (resp.json())
    return resp.json()


def query_playlist(playlist):

    path = 'token.json'
    with open(path) as t:
        token = json.load(t)

    sp = spotipy.Spotify(auth=token)

    data = search_playlist(playlist)
    # get playlists
    playlists = data['playlists']['items']

    for playlist in playlists:
        uri = playlist['uri']
        username = uri.split(':')[2]
        playlist_id = uri.split(':')[4]
        # query playlists
        results = sp.user_playlist(username, playlist_id)
        # separate data by track
        tracks = results['tracks']           
        # lookup       
        for item in tracks['items']:
            track = item['track']
            artist = track['artists'][0]['name']
            print artist


print query_playlist('rock and roll')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your effort! The Spotify Web API console behaves the same as my JavaScript implementation. So that should not be the problem. Your example for sure is a workaround for my problem but I actually want to use the endpoint I mentioned and not the `search` endpoint you used. That is my main concern. I want to use the query parameter field in order to not download data I don't need.